# Error with tensorflow: scatter_nd_op_gpu.cu.o was not created

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to install Tensorflow from sources but I get this error:

```
Error limit reached.
100 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000076fb_00000000-7_scatter_nd_op_gpu.cu.cpp1.ii".
Compilation terminated.
ERROR: /home/rosgori/Python/tengpu/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:4149:1: output 'tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/scatter_nd_op_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/scatter_nd_op_gpu.cu.o' was not created
ERROR: /home/rosgori/Python/tengpu/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:4149:1: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 667.700s, Critical Path: 71.44s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: master
- **Python version**: 3.6.4
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: 0.12.0
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: 5.4.0
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 8.0 / 7.0
- **GPU model and memory**: GeForce GT 740M; 2004MiB

**Exact command to reproduce**:

```
bazel build --verbose_failures -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

When I said *master*, I have not used `r1.8` or `r1.7`. 
Timestamp for *master*:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow()
```

I get: `datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 16, 23, 30, 23, 844800)`

So my questions are:

What is the meaning of that error? Can it be fixed?

**Edit**

Sometimes I get this:

```
20 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000016a4_00000000-7_gather_functor_gpu.cu.cpp1.ii".
ERROR: /home/rosgori/Python/tengpu/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1208:1: output 'tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/gather_functor_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/gather_functor_gpu.cu.o' was not created
ERROR: /home/rosgori/Python/tengpu/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1208:1: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 157.766s, Critical Path: 35.22s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around these issues by -:

1. Installing gcc4.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04

   As per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources binary build packages were built using gcc4 hence there are some incompatibility issues with gcc5+

   ```
      sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
      sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 50
      sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
      sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 50
   ```

And then when running configure give path of gcc as `/usr/bin/gcc-4.9`

2. Editing `/tensorflow/core/platform/macros.h`

   See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19203

   Replace:

   ```
       #define TF_PREDICT_FALSE(x) (__builtin_expect(x, 0))
       #define TF_PREDICT_TRUE(x) (__builtin_expect(!!(x), 1))
   ```

   with

   ```
       #define TF_PREDICT_FALSE(x) (x)
       #define TF_PREDICT_TRUE(x) (x)
   ```

Comment: I partially followed your advice (I didn't install gcc-4.9) and I successfully built the .whl file. Should I mark your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: You can if the answer helped you, but if you don't want to then that's cool too.

Answer (score 1):

add: `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` in bazel build commend

e.g

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks